# Exception RuntimeError in Passenger RequestHandler's client socket (can't modify string; temporarily locked)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, exception, nginx

Receiving below error on rails application hosted on nginx:

```
Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
App 1462 stderr: [ 2015-xx-xx 15:10:29.2082 1494/XXXXXXXXXXXX(Worker 1) utils.rb:85 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Passenger RequestHandler's client socket (can't modify string; temporarily locked) (process 1494, thread XXXXXXXXXXXXX(Worker 1)):

App 1462 stderr:    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb:188:in `read'
App 1462 stderr:    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb:188:in `read'
[ 2015-09-09 15:10:29.2083 1423/7fa8af7fe700 age/Cor/Req/Utils.cpp:95 ]: [Client 6-19] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
App 1462 stderr:    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb:177:in `read_scalar'
App 1462 stderr:    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:217:in `parse_session_request'
App 1462 stderr:    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger
```

Restarted VM and application but receiving same error.

Comment: Do you use threads in your app?

Comment: Yes,we are using mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly causes this error. But as can be found from this link:

http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=582

> We reuse the same buffer over and over for receiving request data, for performance reasons. If your app is somehow able to use our buffer for receiving I/O data as well, in a different thread, then that would result in a race condition with the reporter error as a result.

One user reports resolution of similar problem here:

http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=605

> Indeed, I've narrowed it down to rails-master and/or rack-cache 1.0. When removing caching from latest version of rails (so it does not load rack-cache) everything works.

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Will removing caching be of any help ?

Comment: You should test. It's really rare issue.

Comment: We will try removing caching and test it. Do you have any other workaround for this issue ?